# Shorten PHP code with While Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I'm trying to simplify the code below, but I'm still struggling to understand it. Code A works fine, it outputs a list of images, but Code B just shows a single image

**Code A**

```
<?php
$html_form = '<label>
    <img src="%1$s" width="%2$s" height="%3$s" alt="%4$s" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="%5$s[]" value="%6$s" %7$s/>
</label>';

$html_td = '';
$html = '';

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $select = '';
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array(30, 30));

    if (is_array($instance['thumbs']) && in_array($id, $instance['thumbs'])) {
        $select = 'checked="checked"';
    }
    $html .= sprintf($html_td);
    $html_td = '';
    $html_td .= sprintf($html_form, $thumb[0], $thumb[1], $thumb[2], get_the_title(), $this->get_field_name('thumbs'), $id, $select);
}
$html_form = '          
<p>
    %s
</p>';
printf($html_form, $html);
?>
```

---

My Attempt :
**Code B**

```
<?php
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $id = get_the_ID();

    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array(30, 30));

    $thumbs = is_array($instance['thumbs']) ? (bool) in_array($id, $instance['thumbs']) : true;
}
?>

<p>
    <label>

        <img src="<?php echo $thumb[0] ?>" width="<?php echo $thumb[1] ?>" height="<?php echo $thumb[2] ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title() ?>" />
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('thumbs'); ?>" value="<?php echo $id ?>" <?php checked($thumbs); ?>/>
    </label>
</p>
```

Comment: In Code A, the output is being added to the variable $html inside the loop. Notice the . before the =. In code B you have the while loop, but you keep saving the output into $thumbs, but only after the loop has ended you use it to output. In this way you only get the last post from the result. So you need to either echo the output into the while loop, or save it into a variable like in code A and then output that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it's because you're only echoing out one image.

You could do something like this:

```
<?php while($query->have_posts()):
      $query->the_post();
      $id = get_the_id();
      $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array(30, 30));

      $thumbs = is_array($instance['thumbs']) ? (bool) in_array($id, $instance['thumbs']) : true;?>
<p>
    <label>

        <img src="<?php echo $thumb[0] ?>" width="<?php echo $thumb[1] ?>" height="<?php echo $thumb[2] ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title() ?>" />
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('thumbs'); ?>" value="<?php echo $id ?>" <?php checked($thumbs); ?>/>
    </label>
</p>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

In this case the HTML is inside the while and an image will echo out for each iteration. Also, make sure you have the wp_reset_postdata() or else you may (or may not) encounter bugs in the future.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, I will accept it. However, after using your code. The checkboxes doesnt seem to work properly, I've opened another question on that matter, http://stackoverflow.com/q/30158860 . Please help.

Comment: Your link 404ed for me. My guess on why your checkboxes not working is because of the name attribute, which need to be unique. I see you are grabbing `$this->get_field_name`, but I'm not sure what is doing. You could do something like `name="my-checkbox-<? get_the_ID(); ?>"`. Check the handler code to make sure you are looking at the right index in the request.